# Write a Unit Test to check the variable which is not getting returned by the method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Below is the codeSnippet of what i have to test:
the builder value is getting set but it is not being returned.
Please suggest me a way to test the below method.

```
 public String convertMarkup(request)
 {
     Builder builder = new Response.builder(); 
     String markUpData;
     Map<String,List<String>>collectUrls= collectUrlMethod(request);
     
     if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(collectUrls)){
         builder.setTrackerValue(collectUrls.get(Final_value).get(0));
         builder.build(); 
     }else{
         markUpData="abc"; 
         // rest of the code  
     }
     
     return markUpData; 
 }
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Is it about how to test a particular aspect of the method - in which case I would expect some junit test code in your example? Or is it about why `markupData` is not being set? Also, this snippet may not to compile, given the missing type on `request`. An example reduced to only the key elements would clarify your problem to everyone (including yourself).

Comment: In addition I'd ask for the implementation of collectUrlMethod, since it seems the final result depends on what that method is doing. Anyway, if you want to return the value from the Builder I think you should RETURN something (toString maybe) once the builder.build() method is called... or assign it to the markUpData. Anyway, this code has a lot of smells and it is hard to follow to give to you a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing the code around by introducing a new variable in input request and setting that variable instead of using a new builder. That worked.

```
 public String convertMarkup(requestContext)  {
 Builder builder = new Response.builder(); 
 String markUpData;
 Map<String,List<String>>collectUrls= collectUrlMethod(request);
 if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(collectUrls)){
     requestContext.setTrackerValue(collectUrls.get(Final_value).get(0));
 }else{
     markUpData="abc"; 
     // rest of the code  
 }
 
 return markUpData;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`builder` isn't actually used, unless there's some side effect of calling `builder.build()`, which would be poor design, so you don't have to test it, and in fact you *shouldn't* test it.

The "unit" you are testing is the `convertMarkup()` method, which you test by giving it input and asserting its output - nothing more. Anything inside the method is implementation choice, and is free to be changed at any time, so your unit tests should not depend on it.

For example, a developer may change the implementation to:

```
public String convertMarkup(requestContext) {
    return someExternalService.convertMarkup(requestContext);
}
```

after which all your tests should still compile and pass (assuming the external service works properly, of course).

Code coverage is another matter. Projects should set a minimum code coverage ratio and that may require more unit tests to exercise sufficient code paths, but they are likely valid unit test edges cases anyway.